# Symfony Command have an empty name in production environement

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, command

I'm working on a Symfony2 `Command`, and I have an error when I try to run the command in `prod` environment, but it work perfectly in `dev` :

Everything is fine if I run :

`php app/console mycommand:start`

When I run

`php app/console mycommand:start --env=prod`

I get this error :

```
[LogicException]                                                                               
The command defined in "NameSpace\Of\MyClassCommand" cannot have an empty name.
```

Command definition :

```
services:
  my_service.command:
      class: NameSpace\Of\MyClassCommand
      arguments:
        name: mycommand:start
      tags:
        - { name: console.command }
```

Command :

```
class MyClassCommand extends Command
{

    /**
    * @param InputInterface $input
    * @param OutputInterface $output
    */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // logic
    }

    ...
}
```

As you may notice, I don't overload the `__construct` or the `configure` methods. I tried but it didn't change anything. Same thing if I clean the cache.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the difference between the `prod` and the `dev` environment, to cause this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to clear cache?

Comment: yes, but same result

Comment: Try putting command name in quotes: `'mycommand:start'` just to be extra safe (`:` might be interfering with something)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, Ruslan you were right : clear the cache.
But I had to manually nuke the cache folder, the `cache:clear` command was not enough.

Answer (score 4):

Clearing cache is not working for me. I need to declare base class as `abstract class` to hint Symfony not to register it as command.

```
abstract class BaseCommand {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer for the same problem in Symfony 6.

If a command is defined as...

```
#[AsCommand(name: 'app:export-code-table',description: 'Export code table to a CSV file')]
class ExportCodeTableCommand extends Command
{
  // ...
}
```

And `symfony console list` produces...

```
 [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  The command defined in "App\Command\ExportCodeTableCommand" cannot have an empty name.
```

The problem is that the code is missing a reference...

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
```